# unsafe value used in a resource URL context Angular Error

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe

Hello Guys I want to show a dynamic pdf. At first it was showing me CORS error. I solved that using DOM Sanitizer. Now it is showing me unsafe url Any Help is appreciated.

HTML Code :

```
  <iframe src="{{Url}}"></iframe>
```

TS Code : Here pdfSrc  stores the dynamic generated pdf path;

```
 this.pdfSrc = 'http://192.168.1.183/' + this.pdfPath;
 this.Url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.pdfSrc);
```

Comment: Try this one may be help to you. https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-pipe&hl=en-IN

Comment: Follow this link https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer use this  bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

Comment: Already tried let me try safe pipe

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally got the solution just changed the HTML Part & TS PART AS BELOW

```
<iframe [src]='Url' width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>

constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

this.Url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.pdfSrc);
```

Comment: IM getting error like this ERROR Error: NG0904: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see https://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Comment: yes @Arul. i am getting same error